# Windows updates keep reappearing

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I had this trouble with last months updates and eventually I just hid them, now I'm having trouble with this months. KB2872339 and KB3035131 both insist that they need to be installed when I shutdown my Windows 7 64-bit machine despite the fact they've been installed before (several times now). When I reboot, they don't show up, but after a while when I go to shutdown, I can see the icon telling me that updates are pending. If I then go directly into Windows Update, I can see them and install them and shutdown normally, but they appear again next time I use my computer.

As you can see here, according to the log they were successful installed (several times!):

[image]

Any idea what's going on here and how to fix it?

Comment: open the KB pages for both articles, look at the file versions and compare them on your HDD. if you have the same file versions, ignore the 2 updates in the WU settings

Comment: @magicandre1981 That's pretty much what I did last month, but it seems like the root problem might be somewhere else. I can do that to solve this set of updates, but will it keep happening with the next set of updates?

Comment: I have no idea. I saw this under XP a lot of time, but never under newer Windows versions.